# Sort JSON by field other than Key

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have a JSON string that I want to sort.  I want to sort it by the `'Name'` field.  I can't for the life of me find code that does this.

**Unsorted:**

`{"RU": {"Name": "Russian", "TextDirection": "ltr"}, "FR": {"Name": "French", "TextDirection": "ltr"}, "AR": {"Name": "Arabic", "TextDirection": "rtl"}}`

**Sorted:**

`{"AR": {"Name": "Arabic", "TextDirection": "rtl"}, "FR": {"Name": "French", "TextDirection": "ltr"}, "RU": {"Name": "Russian", "TextDirection": "ltr"}}`

**Update:**

As @jonrsharpe and @martineau pointed out.  I needed to use an array or a list.  I'm not too concerned about the structure. What was originally messing up the sort order was the conversion to json.  By using an array instead, json did not muck with the sort order.

```
[{"Code": "AR", "Name": "Arabic", "TextDirection": "rtl"}, {"Code": "FR", "Name": "French", "TextDirection": "ltr"}, {"Code": "RU", "Name": "Russian", "TextDirection": "ltr"}]
```

Comment: JSON objects (and the Python dictionaries they are mapped to) don't have guaranteed order, so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I removed the reference to key.

Comment: Why do you think you want this?

Comment: Because I want this sorted.  I am passing this back to javascript to load a select object.

Comment: Again, though, *objects aren't sorted*. If order matters, put them in an array.

Comment: Ohhh, you wanted it sorted by Name.

Comment: To emphasize what @jonrsharpe already said, JSON objects (and Python dictionaries representing them) are unordered, so they can't be sorted. However JSON does have a structure which is an [ordered list of values](http://json.org/), commonly called an "array" (or a `list` in Python).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe and martineau for setting me straight on this.  I changed the dictionary to an array and the json conversion kept the original sorting.

Comment: And thanks to whomever for the down votes.

Answer (score 1):

You can user OrderedDict to implement a dictionary with ordered keys in Python.

However, you cannot guarantee that the JSON object will be loaded in order by other applications, because there is no ordering on dictionaries by nature (hashtables).

So, iterating on keys gives you no order guarantee, unless you use a specific class for both Python and JavaScript or if you put your dictionaries into an array whose order is static.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

[How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: The second link has nothing to do with this problem, there are no lists involved.

Comment: This is a reference for the lead given previously in the answer.